# Checkbox click is slow on using ngFor with 1000 row

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angular2-directives, angular2-changedetection

I have 1000 records in my database which has been formatted to a grid using ngFor directive. The user can select multiple records by selecting an individual row checkbox or select all using the main header checkbox.

This approach works fine with less than 200 records (using server sided pagination) on the grid as the size increases so do the response time. For selecting 500 records at once it takes 3-4seconds while for 1000 records more than 6 seconds. The same case occurs with table rendering from JSON.

I used to achieve this feat with Jquery data table and the time to select all 1000 records was less than a second.

JSON from server::

```
dummy = {
          isSelected: false, // for binding ngModel with checkbox
          data1: "test data 1",
          data2: "test data 2",
          data3: "test data 3",
        }
```

table.component.html

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div class="field-checkbox-wrapper" style="background:transparent;">
                <input id="headerCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="" name="check" [ngModel]="isSelected" (ngModelChange)="selectAllRows($event)" class="form-checkbox" >
                <label>asdf</label>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th *ngFor="let map of columnMaps">{{ map.header }}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let record of records; let i = index;" (click)="userRowClicked(record)">
        <td >
            <div class="field-checkbox-wrapper" style="background: transparent;">
                <input type="checkbox" value="" name="check" class="form-checkbox"
                [(ngModel)]="record.uiSelected">
                <label>asdf</label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td *ngFor="let map of columnMaps" [ctStyleCell]="record[map.access(record)]">
            {{ record[map.access(record)] | formatCell:map.format }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

table.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'proctur-checkbox-table',
templateUrl: 'checkbox-table.component.html',
/* changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush */
})
export class CheckboxTableComponent implements OnChanges {
@Input() records: any[];
@Input() settings: ColumnSetting[];
@Input() tableName: string = '';

@Output() userRowSelect = new EventEmitter();
isAllSelected: boolean = false;
columnMaps: ColumnMap[];
selectedRowGroup: any[] = [];

constructor(private rd: Renderer2, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.settings) {
        this.columnMaps = this.settings
            .map(col => new ColumnMap(col));
    } else {
        this.columnMaps = Object.keys(this.records[0]).map(key => {
            return new ColumnMap({ primaryKey: key });
        });
    }

}


selectAllRows(ev) {
    if (ev) {
        this.records.forEach(el => {
            el.uiSelected = true;
        })
    }
    else {
        this.records.forEach(el => {
            el.uiSelected = false;
        })
    }
}


userRowClicked(i){
    this.userRowSelect.emit(i);
}
}
```

Comment: ever heard of paging?

Comment: Already using server sided pagination, but some clients have enormous data around 10000 records and wish to select 1000 at a time for bulk actions like sending promotional emails. Was reading about changeDetectionStrategy but not sure how it would help.